# Remove wiskers from box and wisker plot - ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am able to make a ggplot boxplot with no wiskers or outliers by adding in `outlier.shape = NA,coef = 0` into the `geom_boxplot()` function. When I pass this to `ggplotly()` they both return. I did research and was able to remove the outlier from the viewer with the code below. My question is how do I remove the lines from the plotly object? Additionally I noticed on hover in plotly that the opacity of 0 just hides it from the view but does not remove it from the hover text. Can this also be hidden from hover? Any solution is welcome.

```
library(plotly) 
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars,
      aes(
       x = factor(vs),
       y = mpg
       )
      )+
      geom_boxplot( outlier.shape = NA,coef = 0)
  
p2 <- ggplotly(p1)
#removes outlier 
p2$x$data[[1]]$marker$opacity = 0
```

Note even defining your own stat summary still produces a similar output:

```
q25medq75 <- function(x) {
  v <- c(quantile(x,.25),quantile(x,.25),median(x),
         quantile(x,.75),quantile(x,.75))
  names(v) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  v
}

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg, fill=factor(am))) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=q25medq75, geom="boxplot", colour="black")

p2 <- ggplotly(p1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It offers a very simple, even banal solution.

Our graph looks like this without modification.

```
df = diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), size = 1000),]

p1 = df %>% group_by(cut) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cut, price, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
ggplotly(p1)
```

[image]

And now the same data with minimal modification.

```
f1 = function(x){
  q = quantile(x, c(.25, .75)) 
  x = ifelse(x>q[2], max(x[x<=q[2]]), x)
  x = ifelse(x<q[1], min(x[x>=q[1]]), x)
  x
}

p1 = df %>% group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(price = f1(price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cut, price, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
ggplotly(p1)
```

[image]

Attention. Quartile values may differ slightly from the quartile from original data. This is due to the method of calculating the quantiles. You can experiment with the `type` argument in `quantile` function.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just drew the box and the line for each group?

```
poly_data <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs = vs) %>% 
  summarise(y = list(data.frame(y=c(quantile(mpg, c(.25,.25,.75,.75,.25))))), 
            x = list(data.frame(x=c(vs[1] + c(-.25, .25,.25, -.25,-.25))))) %>%
              unnest(c("x", "y")) 
line_data <-   mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs = vs) %>% 
  summarise(y = median(mpg), 
            x = list(data.frame(x=c(vs[1] + c(-.25, .25))))) %>%
  unnest(c("x")) 



g <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=poly_data, 
               aes(x=x, y=y, group=vs), 
               fill="transparent", 
               col="black") + 
  geom_line(data=line_data,
            aes(x=x, y=y, group=vs))

ggplotly(g)
```

---

### Edit: If `x` is a character vector:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
mtcars$vs <- as.character(mtcars$vs)

poly_data <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs_num = as.numeric(as.factor(vs))) %>%   
  group_by(vs = vs) %>% 
  summarise(y = list(data.frame(y=c(quantile(mpg, c(.25,.25,.75,.75,.25))))), 
            x = list(data.frame(x=c(vs_num[1] + c(-.25, .25,.25, -.25,-.25))))) %>%
  unnest(c("x", "y")) 
line_data <-   mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs_num = as.numeric(as.factor(vs))) %>%   
  group_by(vs = vs) %>% 
  summarise(y = median(mpg), 
            x = list(data.frame(x=c(vs_num[1] + c(-.25, .25))))) %>%
  unnest(c("x")) 



g <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=poly_data, 
               aes(x=x, y=y, group=vs), 
               fill="transparent", 
               col="black") + 
  geom_line(data=line_data,
            aes(x=x, y=y, group=vs))

ggplotly(g)
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! how would this work if x was a character variable? it seems that you are taking advantage of vs being a numeric variable.  Sorry I should have clarified that in the question.

Comment: @Mike I edited the answer to include an example where `x` is a character vector rather than numeric.